# Azure service how notify a posible degradation service?

Tags: azure, service, azure-sql-database

I have got two database (SQL azure) in North America, I'm getting error that the applications can't Access to the server.

I didn't update the application or database, so I supose that there are a problem with sql azure service. How can I notify Microsoft of this problem?

Comment: Notify to who? Your users? Azure has a health dashboard, you can always link to that.

Comment: Notify to Microsoft. I checked health dashboard and there aren't any notification.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To 'notify' Microsoft, you have very limited options.

They have their own [support forums](http://www.windowsazure.com/en-us/support/forums/).

They have their own support ticketing system, [that costs a pretty penny](http://www.windowsazure.com/en-us/support/plans/) but is the fastest way to get their attention.

They have their [dashboard](http://www.windowsazure.com/en-us/support/service-dashboard/), which in my own experience is terrible. It is not a true representation, ever. The **updates** are very very late.

You also have [StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/azure) - but there will be little that we can advise on if there is a problem on the Azure infrastructure side of life.

To help aid in your Azure support woes, I would suggest you get an account with [Pingdom](https://www.pingdom.com/) and get [MetricHubs](https://www.metricshub.com/) for your subscription. These will help in showing what goes down, when, how often, and for how long. It can help show if the problem really is in your application or not.

I would also ensure you have diagnostics set up, and log everything you can.

Many many people forget or don't know about the transient error problems. Microsoft have a huge [article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh680934%28v=pandp.50%29.aspx) on it, but it does trip people up a lot.

The Azure Management Portal should also be able to give you a quick summary of if your roles & instances are actually up, healthy and stable.